# mdVirtualRepeatContainer can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Trying to get `md-virtual-repeat` to work but getting in the console:

`Controller 'mdVirtualRepeatContainer', required by directive 'mdVirtualRepeat', can't be found!`

I have a `<md-virtual-repeat-container>` with a `<tr md-virtual-repeat="row in table" md-item-size="25"></tr>` inside of it. Working with angular-material 0.10.1 and angular 1.4.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to put md-virtual-repeat-container as an attribute of tbody.
I also encountered this error but then changed to this code and it works:

```
<tbody  md-virtual-repeat-container>
  <tr md-virtual-repeat="user in Impl.users">
    <td>{{::user.fname}} {{::user.lname}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Although this directive creates div inside tbody and it breaks table rendering. Same as with md-tabs.

Comment: same issue.  any better way so that it does not break the remaining css?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use virtual repeat in tbody, but instead convert your table to divs. It took me a while until I figured this out, hope it will save some time for someone!

Comment: Since this my answer, a lot of things changed in that library. It's absolutely outdated info.